# cómo muestro imagenes que están en folder diferente a public_html

Tags: laravel, imagen

> -laravel
>   ----App
>   ----bootstrap
>   ----config
>   ----database
>   ----resources
>   ----routes
>   ----storage
>   --------app
>   --------public
>   ------------imagenes
>   ----vendor
>   -public_html
>   -----index.php

El *folder* `public_html` esta en el mismo nivel que `laravel`, en mi servidor local los puedo ver pero el que esta en un `vps` no
ya hice PHP `artisan storage:link`
He intentado estas pero ninguna:

```
<img width="200px" src="{{ url('public/storage/imagenes/pXtGRrmTkHQNFfW3LrKVOnmtYnD2r6WNP1k2rlew.png') }}">
<img src="{{ url('public/imagenes/pXtGRrmTkHQNFfW3LrKVOnmtYnD2r6WNP1k2rlew.png') }}"/>
<img src="<?php echo asset("storage/app/imagenes/muy_bien.png->image")?>"></img>
```

Las imágenes suben bien si: `$imagen = $request->file('imagen')->store('public/imagenes');`

Comment: La ruta debería ser `storage/app/public/imagenes`. Si está así, y hacés un `echo asset('storage/imagenes/imagen.jpg)`, qué te devuelve?

Comment: Si `artisan storage:link` crea un link simbólico de `public/storage` a `storage/app/public`, en tu caso, creo que deberás crear un link simbólico `public_html/storage` a `storage/app/public`. Algo así: `ln -s /path-hasta-tu-proyecto/storage/app/public /path-hasta-public_html/public_html/storage`

Comment: Si hago un echo:  echo asset('storage/imagenes/imagen.jpg);  Muestra https://misitio.com/storage/imagenes/muy_bien.png en texto, si coloco <img src="{{asset('storage/imagenes/muy_bien.png')}}"> en mi computadora veo la imagen pero en el VPS no.

Comment: Ya me funciono la solucion fue  ln -s /home/misitio/laravel/storage/app/public /home/misitio/public_html/storage   Muchas gracias Mario y porloscerros

Comment: @AlvaroGallo te sugerí lo del link simbólico en un comentario porque no sabía si era eso lo que estabas buscando. Si lo resolviste con eso, por favor escribe una respuesta de cómo lo hiciste y márcala como aceptada. Así le podrá servir a otras personas que tengan el mismo problema.

Comment: Esta fue la solucion  ln -s /home/misitio/laravel/storage/app/public /home/misitio/public_html/storage

Answer (score 0):

Como dices que la imágenes las guardas así:

```
$imagen = $request->file('imagen')->store('public/imagenes');
```

Asumo que quieres mostrarlas de una manera parecida a como lo harías teniendo el link simbólico en la carpeta `tu-proyecto/public`. O sea:

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/imagenes/nombre-del-archivo.extension') }}"/>
```

Entonces, si `artisan storage:link` crea un link simbólico de `public/storage` a `storage/app/public`, en tu caso, creo que deberás crear un link simbólico de `public_html/storage` a `storage/app/public` de tu proyecto.
Algo así:

```
ln -s /ruta-completa-hasta-donde-esta-tu-proyecto/tu-proyecto/storage/app/public /ruta-completa-hasta-donde-esta-public_html/public_html/storage
```